npm hangs indefinitely when installing @angular/cli or creating React projects – how to fix it?
I'm a beginner in web development, but I've installed frameworks like Angular and React multiple times without issues. When problems did arise, I usually found solutions quickly. However, this time I'm stuck and can't find a way out despite trying everything I could think of, including checking YouTube tutorials, asking ChatGPT, and searching forums.
The problem is that npm hangs indefinitely when I try to install @angular/cli or create a new React project. The terminal shows no errors; it just freezes and doesn't proceed.
I tried the following steps to resolve the issue:
Restarting my terminal and computer.
Clearing the npm cache using npm cache clean --force.
Disabling the firewall and antivirus temporarily.
Reinstalling Node.js and npm.
Updating npm and Node.js to the latest versions.
Running commands with elevated privileges.
Checking my internet connection, which is stable.
And so on...
My environment:
OS: Windows 10
Node.js Version: v20.17.0
npm Version: 10.8.2
Despite all these attempts, nothing has worked, and I'm at a loss. Has anyone else experienced this issue or knows how to resolve it? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Try npm install --verbose and copy the result here please

looks like my terminal is not connecting to internet i just dont know why, i've heard something about the proxy, tried some things but nothing is working.

Try git bash, powershell or another terminal and share your results please

Still hanging, I've tried to install Bun too and still hanging. I think this gotta be something about my pc's network config. I have installed npm packages a couple times a long time ago in this pc and in others and everything was working well. Btw I Restored the laptop some days ago and the problem persists.
